# The VPN connection failed due to unsuccessful domain name resolution

Tags: cisco, router, vpn, firewall, cisco-anyconnect

We are having trouble when test the VPN remote-access with the above error. It returned domain name successfully when we run nslookup "router_IP" in window CMD but it keeps prompting the error window when we connected via Cisco Any Connect 3.1. We have Router cisco 3925, iOS Version 15.1(1)T1. Please help.

**Updated1: Router's config**

```
aaa new-model  
aaa authentication login AuthenList local  
aaa authorization network vpn-group local  
username vpn1 secret 5 xxxx  

crypto isakmp policy 10  
 encr 3des  
 hash md5  
 authentication pre-share  
 group 2  

ip local pool remote-pool 10.223.131.35 10.223.131.50  

crypto isakmp client configuration group cisco  
 key xxxx  
 pool remote-pool  

crypto ipsec transform-set set1 esp-3des esp-md5-hmac  
crypto dynamic-map map1 10  
 set transform-set set1  
 reverse-route  

crypto map map1 client authentication list AuthenList  
crypto map map1 isakmp authorization list vpn-group  
crypto map map1 client configuration address respond  
crypto map map1 10 ipsec-isakmp dynamic map1  


interface GigabitEthernet0/1  
 ip address A.B.C.D xxxx  
 ip nat outside  
 ip virtual-reassembly  
 duplex auto  
 speed auto  
 crypto map map1
```

The error:

```
The VPN connection failed due to unsuccessful domain name resolution
```

when I entered the domain name of router's interface g0/1 from nslookup (server 8.8.8.8)**

**Updated2:**

I could do forward nslookup but reverse lookup (domain name -> IP) returns failed. Is it a problem?

**Update3:**
In router's config:
ip name-server 8.8.8.8

Comment: You need to edit your question to include the router configuration. Also, include any logs and exact error messages.

Comment: @RonMaupin I updated it, please help

Comment: If there is no DNS name to address resolution, then you can't use the DNS name. You could use the IP address.

Comment: Hi, when I entered the IP address, it said that "Could not connect to server. Please verify Internet connectivity and server address". I'm pretty sure that Internet and IP address are OK, correct.

Comment: Did you configure DNS resolution on the router?

Comment: @Ron Trunk     Hi, I'm not understand well your idea, why do we have to configure it while I can resolve the IP address of router's interface via nslookup (CMD, server 8.8.8.8) ? If it is mandatory, can I use this link?http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipaddr_dns/configuration/15-mt/dns-15-mt-book/dns-config-dns.html#GUID-2186B23A-77D0-4D9B-BD8B-4E4A8D82ABFE

Comment: You have to tell the router how to resolve names.  It needs to know to go to 8.8.8.8 (for example).  the link you provided is to set up a server on the router -- not the same thing.  Use "ip name-server 8.8.8.8"

Comment: I followed your instruction but the problem still exists...

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your problem.   I did a little Goolging, and it appears the problem is in your Anyconnect client.  you may have to reinstall it.

Comment: @RonTrunk      I reinstalled it many times, in both win 7 and 10, but nothing changes

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that configuration of SSL VPN is not completed or incorrect (according to provided part of config). Try to read this [guide](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/anyconnect-secure-mobility-client/200533-AnyConnect-Configure-Basic-SSLVPN-for-I.html) and do a walk thru steps in it.

Comment: I got this error when followed your instructions. Do you know why? R2#copy tftp: flash:/webvpn/
Address or name of remote host []? 192.168.85.128
Source filename []? anyconnect-win-3.1.03103-k9.pkg
Destination filename [/webvpn/anyconnect-win-3.1.03103-k9.pkg]?
Accessing tftp://192.168.85.128/anyconnect-win-3.1.03103-k9.pkg...
Loading anyconnect-win-3.1.03103-k9.pkg from 192.168.85.128 (via FastEthernet0/0): !
%Error opening slot0:/webvpn/anyconnect-win-3.1.03103-k9.pkg (No such device)

Comment: The same error with copy tftp: flash:
%Error opening slot0:/webvpn/anyconnect-win-3.1.03103-k9.pkg (No such device)

Comment: @bim in enable mode execute `dir all-filesystems` and look for what file storages you have. On my ASA5515x there's **disk0:** device.

Comment: @ Andrey        Hi, this is a test env on GNS3, I test it before go on real device but when I hit above command, it only shows system, tmpsys and nvram

Comment: @bim with what virtualization you're running Cisco 3925 in GNS3?

Comment: I run version c7200 on GNS3 to simulate Cisco IOS v15

Comment: @bim ok, you can open settings of your router in GNS and add some space for PCMCIA device under storage tab, 128 MB on example

Comment: I added in both system, nvram, disk0 and disk1 but nothing change :(

Comment: @SpiderlinK I performed some tests, and here's results: operations with flash memory (i.e. PCMCIA cards) only works with **disk1:** card for me. Make sure that you're unchecked **Automatically delete NVRAM and disk files** on "Memories and disks" tab. Try then copy running config to that disk: `copy running-config disk1:/test.cfg`

Comment: @ Andrey I followed your notes but still no luck, do I have to save something after increasing the memory?    R2#show flash:    
Open device slot0 failed (No such device)    
(Try device DISK: for ATA media.)

Comment: R2#copy running-config disk1:  Destination filename []? test.cfg  %Error opening disk1:test.cfg (No such device)

Comment: @SpiderlinK as for me, I've created new device, then unchecked Auto deletion of NVRAM and disks, added 128 MB for PCMCIA storage 2 and powered on device. Then I was able to store files on disk1. I have GNS 2.0.2 and Cisco 7200 IOS 15.2

Answer (score 0):

I received this message today while working at home on my FDA laptop. "The VPN connection failed due to unsuccessful domain name resolution". When I called FDA's helpdesk I found that we connect to a different VPN from Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client.  It's called VPN-Preferred. When I chose that instead of "Remote Connection" I connected to VPN-Preferred in a snap. No more issues.